# SQLCMD Exporting 16.5 Million Rows

Tags: sql-server, sqlcmd

I am exporting a table to a TSV file using sqlcmd, and I am running into issues. The table has 16+ million rows and about 55 columns.

The problem is that it does not export the full table, but seems to stop randomly at various points (i am guessing a timeout?)  Each time a different number of rows are exported and each time the file is of a slightly different size (indicating that I am not hitting any row or size limit).

I am not using any timeout switch (meaning the default of "as long as it takes" is used).

Here is my command (with most columns removed for simplification and illustration purposes):

```
sqlcmd -U myUsername -P myPassword -S SERVERNAME -d "DBNAME" -Q "SELECT ROW_KEY, ISNULL(CARRIER_ID, ''),ISNULL(CONVERT(VARCHAR(19),ORDER_DATETIME,120),''),ISNULL(HEIGHT, ''),ISNULL(RESIDENTIAL_CHARGE, '') FROM MYTABLE" -o "OUTPUT_FILE.txt" -h-1 -s"|" -W
```

I wonder if it could have something to do with timeouts or the use of ISNULL() on all of the columns (although when i run the query in sql server management studio I get the correct number of rows returned e.g. 16 million + )?

Again, I get about 4-8 million rows each time, but never the full amount. I am in a sql server 2k5 db, and running sqlcmd from a remote machine with sql server 2k8.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You'll probably want to do this with bcp, which is intended for this kind of thing. It would be something like this:

```
bcp "SELECT ROW_KEY, ISNULL(CARRIER_ID, ''),ISNULL(CONVERT(VARCHAR(19),ORDER_DATETIME,120),''),ISNULL(HEIGHT, ''),ISNULL(RESIDENTIAL_CHARGE, '') FROM MYTABLE" queryout OUTPUT_FILE.txt -c -S <servername> -U <login_name> -P <password>
```

Replace -c with -w if you're dealing with nvarchar/nchar, and want Unicode output.

Comment: +1 for suggesting bcp. I would suggest using `-n` to bcp out in Native Format which is very fast compared to regular bcp. You wont be able to see the contents of the file as they are in binary, so there is no conversion involved and it will cut down your time as well.

Answer (score 3):

Might consider using [Invoke-Sqlcmd](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc281720%28v=sql.100%29.aspx) since you are working from a machine with SQL 2008 installed. You do not get the column separator `-s` option as `sqlcmd` does, but within PowerShell you could export it to XML or CSV.

Basic syntax for your query would be:

```
$q = @"
SELECT ROW_KEY, 
   ISNULL(CARRIER_ID, ''),
   ISNULL(CONVERT(VARCHAR(19),ORDER_DATETIME,120),''),
   ISNULL(HEIGHT, ''),
   ISNULL(RESIDENTIAL_CHARGE, '') 
FROM MYTABLE
"@

Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance MyServer -Database MyDatabase -Query $q -Username  -
Password  | Export-Csv MyFile.txt
```

Then if you absolutely needed to keep a particular separator between the columns you could just modify your query a bit:

```
SELECT ROW_KEY + '|' + 
   ISNULL(CARRIER_ID, '') + '|' +
   ISNULL(CONVERT(VARCHAR(19),ORDER_DATETIME,120),'') + '|' +
   ISNULL(HEIGHT, '') + '|' +
   ISNULL(RESIDENTIAL_CHARGE, '')
FROM MYTABLE
```

Comment: `Export-Csv` takes a parameter `delimiter`

Comment: I tried _PowerShell 5.1_ with `Invoke-SqlCmd` and a table with millions of rows. It turns out that the whole data set being exported is collected in memory (memory usage grows up to 7GB in my case). _Powershell_ is also painfully slow in comparison with e.g. F# or C#

Comment: @JeffereyCave it defaults the delimiter to a comma, so unless you want something else other than that it is not a required parameter.

Comment: @IvanAkcheurov PowerShell itself is not slow, you are dealing with the Invoke-Sqlcmd command that is slow. When you isse that command and pipe it to something else it has to read all the data in before it will pass it down...it does not stream it in any manner. If you are dealing with a large amount of data you will be better of using the BCP utility, that is what it is meant to do.

Comment: @ShawnMelton, just tested a sample. Please try the following: `gc .\1500MB.txt | measure` in _PowerShell_ (took 82 seconds) and `let length = readLines "1500MB.txt" |> Seq.length` in _F# Interactive_ (took 5 seconds).
_PowerShell_ is 16x times slower but it doesn't eat memory anymore as it used to. _F#_ is brilliant as always :)

Comment: Get-Content is known to be slow...anything will be faster than that command. https://www.google.com/amp/s/rkeithhill.wordpress.com/2007/06/17/optimizing-performance-of-get-content-for-large-files/amp/

Comment: At the end of the day you pick the process or language that fits the job you need done and are familiar.

Comment: -1 because the OP explicitly talks about 16.5 millions rows. At first it seems you have not tested Invoke-SqlCmd with many rows, but then you later add a comment that invalidates your own answer, saying that Invoke-SqlCmd is not able to pipe with low memory usage and that we'd better use BCP. About the separator option, you say there's none in the answer, but then you add a comment suggesting there might be one and comma is just a default (so in the end we don't know)... That's the way to go to confuse people and make them loose time.

Comment: @JohanBoulé guess that is why this is not the selected answer ;)

Answer (score 0):

What @db2 said.  If that doesn't work, try segmenting your data.  If you have an integer ID field, you could add

```
 WHERE ID % @NumSegments = @SegmentNumber
```

Loop for all values of @SegmentNumber from zero to one less than the number of segments, and you should get all records.  Microsoft SQL's implementation of modulus only returns positive numbers, unlike some (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4412179/best-way-to-make-javas-modulus-behave-like-it-should-with-negative-numbers/4412200#4412200) languages.